# Periodic Behavior of a Two-Body Problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions, celestial-mechanics

Given the following equations and parameters: does the orbit repeat? If not, why? and what would make it repeat?

*Any clarification on what makes an orbit periodic would be greatly appreciated!*

I solved the two-body problem with ode45 in Matlab and obtained the following graphs for the position and velocity of the orbit through multiple periods. From the graphs, I see no reason why the orbit would not repeat, but I want to make sure I am not missing something due to the relative/absolute error limits in ode45.

Orbit Position/Velocity: 
[image: Position of Orbit]
[image: Velocity of Orbit]

Equations of Motion:
$$\ddot x + \mu\frac{x}{r^3} = 0 $$
$$\ddot y + \mu\frac{y}{r^3} = 0 $$
$$\ddot z + \mu\frac{z}{r^3} = 0 $$

where: $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ and $\mu = 3.986004 \space\space * \space\space 10^{14} \space m^3/s^2$

Comment: plotting the xy, xz, ,yz planes the orbits are slightly different (in the 5th decimal) but that is most likely due to computational rounding/error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the equation in its vector form,

$$\ddot {\vec{r}} = -\mu\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3} $$

which is the equation for orbiting movements due to gravitational force. It follows an elliptical trajectory in a plane formed by the radial vector and the velocity. It repeats itself.